# Turn old boot disk into secondary drive without losing data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 2TB drive with XBMCBuntu 12.04.3 installed on it and also about 1.5TB of data.I have a new, small HDD (40GB) and want to install the OS on it.

I would like to keep the data on the HDD but just turn it into a data drive. I don't have another 2TB drive I could transfer the data off to temporarily. Is there any way I can do this without buying a 2TB external drive?

Comment: so you want to delete the OS partition the 2TB drive and expand the data partition to the deleted OS partition ? once you boot using the new HDD (with your newly installed OS) just use fdisk to do this. heres a guide to resize a partition, http://www.htmlgraphic.com/how-to-resize-partition-without-data-loss/

Comment: @nixgadgets Not quite, there is only one usable partition on the 2TB, I want to keep the data in my home directory

Comment: so if i understand you correctly youd like to move the data in the home directory of your old installation (worth 1.5TB) to an actual data partition ?

Comment: @nixgadgets yes

Comment: unfortunately, that cant be done without backing up your data. assuming you have a tower instead of a laptop can you not get a 2TB HDD and back up your data ?

Comment: @nixgadgets I've gone and done that, just wanted to see if there was a software solution before spending money. Thanks for the help, feel free to chuck that in as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: theres always software solutions like Acronis but you still need sufficient space to backup and compress your data. specially if its 1.5TB. but glad you got it sorted !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that cant be done without backing up your data. Assuming you have a tower instead of a laptop get a 2TB HDD and back up your data.

Comment: This statement is wrong. You can easily move partitons and enlarge them forward. Use Gparted.